# Apollo GraphQL merge cached data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, graphql, apollo

I have a page that consists of 2 components and each of them has its own request for data
for example

```
<MovieInfo movieId={queryParamsId}/>

const GET_MOVIE_INFO = `gql
  query($id: String!){
   movie(id: $id){
    name
    description
 }
}`
```

Next component

```
<MovieActors movieId={queryParamsId}/>

const GET_MOVIE_ACTORS = `gql
  query($id: String!){
   movie(id: $id){
    actors
 }
}`
```

For each of these queries I use apollo hook

const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_DATA, {variable: {id: queryParamsId}}))

Everything is fine, but I got a warning message:

> Cache data may be lost when replacing the movie field of a Query object.
> To address this problem (which is not a bug in Apollo Client), either ensure all objects of type Movie have IDs, or define a custom merge function for the Query.movie field, so InMemoryCache can safely merge these objects: { ... }

It's works ok with google chrome, but this error affects Safari browser. Everything is crushing. I'm 100% sure it's because of this warning message. On the first request, I set Movie data in the cache, on the second request to the same query I just replace old data with new, so previous cached data is undefined. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: in other words: "your queried (requested) `movie` [type] should contain `id` property" (beside `name`, `description` or `actors`) - otherwise it is not cache'able - [you can use other named unique field and conversion function] - cache just works this way, it wants unique objects

Comment: "*ensure all objects of type Movie have IDs*" is quite clear imo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved!

```
 cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          YOUR_FIELD: {
            merge(existing = [], incoming: any) {
              return { ...existing, ...incoming };
              // this part of code is depends what you actually need to do, in my 
              case i had to save my incoming data as single object in cache
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: using `id` in both queries does the same

Comment: I had a similar issue and I am retuning ids in both, but it doesn't work for me @xadm

Comment: @xadm My man... was about to start pulling my hair before I saw your comment.

Comment: Using `id` in both queries worked for me as well.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the same solution mentioned by Thomas but a bit shorter

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        YOUR_FIELD: {
          // shorthand  
          merge: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

This is same as the following

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        YOUR_FIELD: {
          merge(existing, incoming, { mergeObjects }) {
            return mergeObjects(existing, incoming);
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers still work, but as of Apollo Client >= 3.3 there's an [easier option](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/#configuring-merge-functions-for-types-rather-than-fields) that doesn't require specifying specific fields or a custom merge function. Instead, you only have to specify the type and it will merge all fields for that type:

```js
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    YOUR_TYPE_NAME: {
      merge: true,
    }
  }
});
```

From your example query, I'd guess that an `id` field should be available though? Try requesting the ID in your query, that should solve the problem in a much more ideal way.

Comment: I'm confused; why wouldn't that be the default behavior for types with an `id` field. Apollo can tell two objects are the same object if they have the same id, so just merge them.

Comment: @matrixfrog it is the default behavior for types with an `id` field, this setup is only for special cases where one is not available for whatever reason (definitely preferable to design the API side such that this isn't necessary). (Just updated my answer to be clear on this)

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but I was still getting a warning, even with `id`s on all objects. However, since posting that comment, I think I solved it by upgrading to the latest Apollo Client version.

Answer (score 3):

Had same issue with **inconsistency of data values vs. our schema**. A value type within an entity was missing the **id** value. *Caused by an incomplete data migration.*

Temporary solution:

```
const typePolicies = {
      PROBLEM_TYPE: {
        keyFields: false as false,
      },
      PARENT_TYPE: {
        fields: {
          PROBLEM_FIELD: {
            merge: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
```