# Cache data may be lost when replacing the my field of a Query object

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, graphql-js

this my code

```
const NewVerificationCode = () => {
  const { loading, error, data = {}, refetch } = useQuery(CONFIRMATION_CODE, {
    skip: true,
    onError: (err) => {},
  });
  console.log(loading, error, data);

  if (loading || error) {
    return <ErrorLoadingHandler {...{ loading, error }} />;
  }

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        refetch();
        e.preventDefault();
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <button type="submit" className="signUpbutton">
          {"Send the message again"}
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

const CONFIRMATION_CODE = gql`
  query {
    my {
      sendNewTokenForConfirmation
    }
  }
`;
```

when i make a request i get a warning

> Cache data may be lost when replacing the my field of a Query object.
>
> To address this problem (which is not a bug in Apollo Client), either ensure all >objects of type My have IDs, or define a custom merge function for the Query.my >field, so InMemoryCache can safely merge these objects
> existing:

```
    {"__typename":"My","getUser{"__typename":"User","email":"shakizriker0022@gmail.com"}}

incoming: {"__typename":"My","sendNewTokenForConfirmation":"SUCCESS"}
```

> For more information about these options, please refer to the documentation:

I followed the links.

I read the documentation and realized that the problem is in the apollo client cache (typePolicies).

But how should I solve this problem I just can't figure out.

What should i write in typePolicies to get rid of the warning ?.

Answer (score 12):

You may need to return an id for Apollo to uniquely identify that object in the cache.
I think this issue is similar to yours:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63123558/apollo-graphql-merge-cached-data?rq=1)

```
const CONFIRMATION_CODE = gql`
  query {
    my {
      id
      sendNewTokenForConfirmation
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, my should return id.I tried it but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

**Every** object should return id, _id or alternatively a custom id field (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration) for **automatic merges to function**.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Product: {
      keyFields: ["custom-id-field"],
    },
  },
});
```

**(!)People often forget that cache operations require the same variables used for the initial query (!)**

Mutation Sample (adding a purchase):

```
update(cache, { data: NewPurchase } }) => {
  let productCache = cache.readQuery({
    query: productQuery,
    variables: {
      id: productId
    }
  })
 
  cache.writeQuery({
    query: productQuery,
    variables: { id: productId },
    data: {
      Product: {
        ...productCache.Product,
        purchases: productCache.Product.purchases.concat(NewPurchase)
      }
    }
  });
 };
}
```

(Important: Each Purchase also requires it's own individual id that needs to be returned)

Comment: What to do if the object was deleted?

Comment: you can use a filter to remove the object:


purchases: productCache.Product.purchases.filter(purchase => purchase.id != RemovedPurchased.id)

Answer (score 0):

Locate the file where you create ApolloClient and provide a merge method for your field:

```
 cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
        Query: {
            fields: {
                my: {
                    merge(existing, incoming) {
                        return incoming;
                    }
                },
            },
        },
    }
}),
```

See this [post](https://medium.com/@dexiouz/fix-cache-data-may-be-lost-when-replacing-the-getallposts-field-of-a-query-object-in-apollo-client-7973a87a1b43) for more info