# refetchQueries after running a mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

Previously, I was running a mutation somewhat like this:

```
export const useEditLocationName = () => {

  const [editFavoriteLocationName] = useEditFavoriteLocationNameMutation({
    refetchQueries: [{ query: GetMyFavouritePlacesDocument}],
    awaitRefetchQueries: true,
    onCompleted: () => {
      Alert.alert('Name');
    },
    onError: () => {
      Alert.alert('Oops');
    },
  });

  const editLocationName = async (
    favouritePlaceId: number,
    customisedName: string,
  ) => {
    editFavoriteLocationName({
      variables: {
        id: favouritePlaceId,
        label: customisedName
      },
    });
    return null;
  };
  return editLocationName;
};
```

Every time I run this mutation, the results of the `useGetMyFavouritePlacesQuery` i.e the `GetMyFavouritePlacesDocument` got updated automatically (wherever this query was being used). This worked perfectly then there were no parameters needed for the `useGetMyFavouritePlacesQuery`. However, now that there are some changes in the api, I need to pass an `id`to the query in order for it return results. How can I do so?

I cannot pass variables directly to the `GetMyFavouritePlacesDocument` and I can also not use the hook here. How else can I efficiently refetch data every time I run this mutation?

Answer (score 0):

If you return the id in the mutation response and possibly a little other unique data about the data then Apollo will automatically update the cache

Here is an example https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-update-the-apollo-clients-cache-after-a-mutation-79a0df79b840/

Comment: This seemed to work but then it gives me this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423578/cache-data-may-be-lost-when-replacing-the-my-field-of-a-query-object even though I am already returning unique ids & some other info. The error suggests me to define a custom merge function. How could I do so?

Comment: I added more code & details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63918330/unable-to-update-cache-after-mutation